# Scoped service in Hangfire Job Filter

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, hangfire

After searching & reading possibly every discussion related to the topic in question, there seemed not to be a clear (or even unclear)
solution to this.

I have a job filter that I want to apply to every job. What I want to do is: when the job fails (goes to `FailedState`, which happens when the max retry attemps exceed OR it is thrown in that state manually), I want to log a custom, user-friendly exception message to the database (my custom table).

```
public class WorkflowJobFailureAttribute : JobFilterAttribute, IApplyStateFilter {

    public WorkflowJobFailureAttribute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) {
        // Getting my required services here
    }

    public void OnStateApplied(ApplyStateContext context, IWriteOnlyTransaction transaction) 
    {
        var failedState = context.NewState as FailedState;
        if (failedState != null) {
            // - HANDLE FAILED STATE HERE -
                
            // You can get the exception (which is of type `Exception`) using: `failedState.Exception`
        }
    }
}
```

But every darn example/suggestion I was was about registering the filter globally (`GlobalJobFilters.Filters.Add(new WorkflowJobFailureAttribute(serviceProvider));` in `Startup.cs`). But this is the *ROOT* service provider, so it will not work with scoped lifetime.

There is a possible 'workaround', suggested by **balazs hideghety** in the comments [here](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/extensibility/using-job-filters.html#comment-3530139563). But before diving deep into that (because it feels like a 'distant' solution), I would like to know: has anyone, in his experience, solved this problem?

Comment: Inject scoped service provider factory and then create the scoped service provider as needed

Comment: Did you try the `.AddTrancient()`?

Comment: @PaulSinnema excuse me but where/what are you talking about?

Comment: In your Startup.cs use `services.AddTrancient<ICls, Cls>()`.

Comment: @PaulSinnema that's not the case. Also, do you note the word "hangfire"?

Comment: Yeah, I know what HangFire is. Used it myself but that was in .Net 4.7.2. But I see you have your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inject a scoped service provider factory and then create the scoped service provider as needed

```
public class WorkflowJobFailureAttribute : JobFilterAttribute, IApplyStateFilter {
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory;

    public WorkflowJobFailureAttribute(IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory) {
        this.scopeFactory = scopeFactory; 
    }

    public void OnStateApplied(ApplyStateContext context, IWriteOnlyTransaction transaction) {
        var failedState = context.NewState as FailedState;
        if (failedState != null) {
            using (IServiceScope scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope()) {
                IServiceProvider serviceProvider = scope.ServiceProvider;

                // Getting my required services here

                // - HANDLE FAILED STATE HERE -
                
                // You can get the exception (which is of type `Exception`) using: `failedState.Exception`
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the preceding code, an explicit scope is created and the service provider can be used to resolve scoped services.

Comment: I feel stupid rn. For some reason I was doing the same, but initializing the scope in the constructor instead...effect of tiredness atm xP I will try this and provide feedback.

Comment: @Ergis Yeah, when injecting service providers (Service Locator) try to avoid doing the resolutions in the constructor.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me out. Sometimes the solution is in front of your eyes, but talking to someone always helps. :)